# PHP array manipulation

Tags: php, arraylist

Can any one please give me an idea to manipulate the array in PHP.

I have an array like this order

```
$test = array(
              "0"=>"62"
              "1"=>"61"
              "2"=>"60"
              "3"=>"53"
              "4"=>"52"
              "5"=>"51");
```

But i need to rearrange or sort it into this order.

```
$test = array(
              "2"=>"60"
              "1"=>"61"
              "0"=>"62"
              "5"=>"51"
              "4"=>"52"
              "3"=>"53");
```

Please help me...

Comment: What is the "rule" of your order?

Comment: There is no obvious ordering in your second example. How do you want us to arrive at that given different numbers?

Comment: So you want to sort by value where the FIRST numbers are descending and the other digits are ascending what about 3 digit numbers? What would be the desire order for 61,62,63,101,110,121,122,130....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(only works for two digit numbers, see @Olivers comment)*

Here you go:

```
function csort($a, $b) {
    $ta = floor($a / 10);
    $tb = floor($b / 10);
    if( $ta !== $tb) {
        return $tb - $ta;
    }
    return $a - $b;
}

$test = array(
              "0"=>"62",
              "1"=>"61",
              "2"=>"60",
              "3"=>"53",
              "4"=>"52",
              "5"=>"51");

usort($test, "csort");
print_r($test);
```

prints

```
 Array
(
    [0] => 60
    [1] => 61
    [2] => 62
    [3] => 51
    [4] => 52
    [5] => 53
)
```

Reference: [`usort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Or [`ausort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) if you want to keep the index.

Answer (score 0):

maybe will help:

[Sorting Arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)